# Read line from list box every 3 seconds?

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

I'm trying to read a line from a list box in order every 3 seconds and showing the item read in a text box ? But I am unsure of what I  need to do to make it loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, that's great.  What's wrong?  You can [edit] to provide 1) the code in which you're attempting to do this, and 2) a description of what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't a whole lot of information to go on, here is what I would do if I wanted to read something every 3 seconds:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(3000);      // Timer in milliseconds (3 seconds)
timer.AutoReset = true;             // Auto reset the timer
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
    // 1. Read the list box
    // 2. Disply read item in text box
};
timer.Start();
```

The code above will instantiate a timer with a period of 3 seconds and the Elapsed event will fire every 3 seconds.

Comment: This is perfect :) do you know how I would be able to read the lines in order so starting from the top read a line move to the next read a line move to the next and so on ?

Comment: You could just get the items from the list box: `var myItems = myListBox.Items` and then iterate through them: `foreach(var item in myItems) {...}`. If the item are already sorted in the ListBox then they should be pulled in the same order. If they are not sorted, then you will need to find something to sort them by.

Answer (score 0):

Another way how you can do that is the using [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private readonly int _delayInMiliSeconds = 3000;
private CancellationTokenSource _token;
private bool _isStoped;

public void StartUpdate()
{
    if (this._isStoped)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    this._token = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.Update();
}

public void StopUpdate()
{
    if (this._isStoped)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    this._isStoped = true;
    this._token.Cancel();
}

private void Update()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (!this._token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this._delayInMiliSeconds), this._token.Token);

            //your repeted action has to be called here
        }
    }, this._token.Token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in a separated thread for your UI continue working.
See how to use [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and implement it with your needs.